# Get all attributes of a Django model field except ptr

Tags: django

I'm trying to render all the attributes of a model in a template--I'm pretty close.  I have these models:

```
class A(models.Model):

class B(A):

class C(B):

  def get_fields(self):
     return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field
             in C._meta.fields if field not in (B._meta.fields)]
```

It's working perfectly except for including in my template:
   `b ptr = 123` where 123 is the pk of the object.

I originally saw that it included `A ptr` which I now see is an attribute of `B`, so excluding all the `B._meta.fields` took care of it.  Is there a way to get rid of `b ptr` without hardcoding it in?

Comment: I don't know for sure if this will work, but it may help.  Could you try adding something like  `and not field.name.endswith('_ptr')`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would work, but I was hoping to avoid hardcoding it in like that.